# Cant override blocks in included twig template

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

Please help me understand the right way to use template inheritance in twig.

I have a template *base.html.twig* that all my other templates extend. This contains the html, head, body, etc. tags and a few blocks.

I would like to move the < head > section from the *base.html.twig* template into its own file *head.html.twig*. If I use the include directive then the title block in that section no longer gets overridden properly by the extending templates.

I determined that I could work around this by setting the title as a variable in the extending template and passing it in my include statement. But now I have pages that need extra bits of javascript loaded in the < head > section, so I have to add variables to indicate which of those to load...

Obviously this is a horrible kludge. What is the right way to do this?

EDIT: At the suggestion of @goto I tried replacing include with embed. Now my code looks like:

```
{# base.html.twig #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% embed 'AppBundle::head.html.twig' %}
    {% block title %}My Company Name{% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

{# head.html.twig #}
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <!-- load other css, js, etc -->
</head>

{# page.html.twig #}
{% extends 'AppBundle::base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}{{ page.title }} - My Company Name{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    {{ page.content|raw }}
{% endblock %}
```

But this doesnt work, the title is always "My Company Name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I needed the "use" tag:

```
{# base.html.twig #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% use 'AppBundle::head.html.twig' %}
{% block head %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

{# head.html.twig #}
{% block head %}
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}My Company Name{% endblock %}</title>
        <!-- load other css, js, etc -->
    </head>
{% endblock %}

{# page.html.twig #}
{% extends 'AppBundle::base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}{{ page.title }} - My Company Name{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    {{ page.content|raw }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for example you have a *base.html.twig*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ Someurl }}">

    {% block css %}
     ..... ///some css here
    {% endblock %}

    {% block js %}
    ...//javascript goes here
    {% endblock %}
    .......
```

With twig inheritance you can ovverride any of these blocks in your child like this:

*child.html.twig*

```
{% extends ::base.html.twig %}
{% block js %}
    {{ parent() }}
   .... your new js
{% endblock %}
```

With key word   *{{ parent() }}* you will include existing data from base template to your current one, without it you will get clear block.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My setup is slightly more complicated though. Please see my edit for an example.

Comment: @Aaron read the example of `embed` [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html)

Comment: Thanks, I've studied that page quite a bit and perhaps I am slow but I can't see how I can use it here. In all their examples the embed tag (and thus the embedded content) goes in the child template which is also where the block is redefined. In my example I am trying to include the head.html.twig content in the base template, but the title block is (re)defined in page.html.twig. It seems the embed is really intended to go in the child template (page.html.twig) but that obviously doesn't work for me here. I tried adding it to the base template (see above) but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try embed instead of include, it allows you to redefine internal blocks of the included part:

```
{% embed "YourBundle:Acme:_embedded.html.twig" %}
    {% block header%}
        A new header
    {% endblock header%}
    {% block body%}
        A new body
    {% endblock body%}
{% endembed %}
```

See the [the doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html) for more information