# Extending twig blocks in a complicated scenario

Tags: twig

Let's say I have these twig templates:

*base.twig*

```html
{# base.twig #}

<html>
  <head>
    {% include 'head_js.twig' %}
  </head>
  <body>
     {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

*head_js.twig*

```html
{# head_js.twig #}

{% block headJS %}
  <script src='/js/some-script.js'></script>
  {% block headJSExtra %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

*page.twig* (the one loaded by the controller)

```html
{# page.twig #}

{% extends base.twig %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Widget 1</p>
  {% include 'widget.twig' with { name: 'foo' } %}

  <p>Widget 2</p>
  {% include 'widget.twig' with { name: 'bar' } %}
{% endblock %}
```

*widget.twig*

```html
{# widget.twig #}

{% if wigetAlreadyIncluded is not defined %}
  {% block headJSExtra %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src='/js/widget.js'></script>
  {% endblock %}

  {% set widgetAlreadyIncluded = true %}
{% endif %}
<p>My name is {{ name }}</p>
```

This code doesn't work (can't use parent() in widget.twig as it's not extending or using any template), but it should illustrate what I'm trying to achieve. The basic idea is:

- In order to work, *widget.twig* requires a js library to be loaded in  as a  tag in the .
- The widget can be rendered several times in one page.
- Other widgets should be able to also add their own  tags in the  in this fashion, but they shouldn't override previous added  tags (they should be appended).
- I don't want to add more than once any  tag required by any widget found in the page.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this would be greatly appreciated. I've read two SO related questions with no luck at all.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29132604/4949663
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18160977/4949663

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a good answer in the twig github issue tracker.
https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2275